# Difficulty with understanding the semantics of the following equivalences

Tags: logic

I know that the rules for removing quantifiers from the antecedent of a conditional are as follows: 
**(∀x)φ(x) → ψ ⇔ (∃x)(φ(x) → ψ)** and **(∃x)φ(x) → ψ ⇔ (∀x)(φ(x) → ψ)**, provided that *x* is not free in *ψ*.
I also know that the rules for removing quantifiers from the consequent are as follows:
**φ → (∀x)ψ(x) ⇔ (∀x)(φ → ψ(x))** and **φ → (∃x)ψ(x) ⇔ (∃x)(φ → ψ(x))**, provided that *x* is not free in *φ*.

Now, I understand how to derive these equivalences syntactically. However, I can't seem to grasp how the first two can be semantically equivalent.
For example, how can two sentences such as *"If all x are wet, then it's raining"* and *"There exists an x such that if x is wet, then it's raining"* can be equivalent?
Moreover, provided that *x* is not free in *ψ*, isn't **(∀x)φ(x) → ψ** equivalent to **(∀x)(φ(x) → ψ)**? Which would result in the absurd equivalence: **(∀x)(φ(x) → ψ) ⇔ (∃x)(φ(x) → ψ)**.

I think that my difficulty here arises from a misunderstanding of the significance of the parentheses in the aforementioned equivalences. Please provide examples in your answer if you can.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> how can two sentences such as "(If all **x** are wet, then it's raining)" and "There exists an **x** such that (if **x** is wet, then it's raining)" can be equivalent?

A simple approach to this equivalence, that holds only in classical logic, is to exploit the so-called [Material implication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Material_implication_(rule_of_inference)) rule :

> **(P → Q) ≡ (¬ P ∨ Q)**.

Thus, we have that : "(If all **x** are wet, then it's raining)" is equivalent to : "Either (not all **x** are wet) or it's raining", i.e "Either (there exists an **x** which is not wet) or it's raining".

Now we have to use the fact that the existential quantifier "distribute" over *or* and the fact that "it's is raining" is equivalent to "there is an **x** such that it's raining", due to the key-fact that **x** is not free in "it's raining".

Thus, the last step is to move the existential quantifier in front of the formula to get :

> "There exists an **x** such that (either **x** is not wet or it's raining)."

---

We can show the semantical equivalence of :

> **(∀x βx → α) ↔ ∃x(βx → α)**

this way.

Let **M** a structure whatever, with domain **D**.

Two cases :

(i) **∀x βx** is False. In this case **(∀x βx → α)** is True.

This means that there is an **a** in **D** such that **βa** is False.

Thus, **(βa → α)** is True, which means that **(βx → α)** is True for some **x**.

And thus, also **∃x(βx → α)** is True.

(ii) **∀x βx** is True.

Two subcases :

(iia) **α** is True. In this case **(∀x βx → α)** is True.

But if **α** is True, also **(βx → α)**, irrespective of the value of **x**, and thus also **∃x(βx → α)** is True.

(iib) **α** is False. In this case **(∀x βx → α)** is False.

The fact that **∀x βx** is True imples that **βa** is True, for every **a** in **D**.

Thus **(βa → α)** is False, for every **a** in **D**, which means that **∃x(βx → α)** is False.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying the problem. I understand how the universal conditional implies the existential so no problem here. However, I still don't get how the existential conditional also implies the universal.

Comment: @OfekAman - not clear... the two are equivalent : when (∀x βx → α) is True, also ∃x(βx → α) is True. When (∀x βx → α) is False, also ∃x(βx → α) is False.

Comment: Oh, I see it now. The two expressions always get yhe same truth value and therefore are equivalent. Thank you!